number of $k$-member families of subsets of an $n$-set

How do I count the number of distinct k-member families of subsets of an $n$-set?

My Approach
Given that there are $2^n$ distinct subsets of the $n$-set, we first tried the combination of $2^n$ taken 5 at a time, but this does not take into account the fact that more than one member of the family may be empty. If some of the members of a family are non-empty, they must not overlap.

Hint
Consider you have deck then you have to choose 5 cards of them. In how many ways you can make it.
I will encourage you to think about this for sometime before reading any further.
Answer
Like in deck you can choose 5 cards in $\binom{52}{5}$.
Similarly you can district k-memeber family from n- set by $\binom{n}{k}$.

We wish to find the number of possible collections ${A,B,C,D,E}$ where $A,B,C,D,E\subseteq{1,...,n}$ are pairwise disjoint but we allow each of these sets to be empty as well.

I got it, the answer would be $(k+1)^n$, like having $k+1$ boxes to put the $n$ distinct object, where one of the boxes is a "trash" box, i.e., not choosing that object at all. :)
